# How can I insert one register into related tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, authentication

I have this table

**Usuario**

- id_usuario (FK)
- User
- Password
- FristName
- Lastname
- E-mail
- Photo_avatar

And I have this other table:

**Imagenes**

- id_imagen (FK)
- id_usuario
- Picture
- Picture_name

The relation:

```
Usuario.id_usuario = Imagenes.id_usuario
```

And I try to insert a picture into pictures but I need to take the `id_usuario` from `Usuario`

This is for a login system, and when I try to insert a picture, I have to do a query inserting the `id_usuario`. I want to write code that will automatically recognize the id for the moment when I insert the picture in `Imagenes`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Writing your own authentication code is **bad**. It's very easy to build something that _seems_ to work, even passes all your tests, but still has subtle flaws that won't become apparent until a year later when you find out you where hacked six months ago.

Comment: You are using web forms?

Comment: I using windows form aplicattions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use scope_identity() to get the identity value generated by the previous insert statement.  So something like:

```
    declare @id_usuario int

    insert into Usuario 
    ([User], [Password], FristName, Lastname, [EMail], Photo_avatar)
    values (@User, @Password, @FristName, @Lastname, @EMail, @Photo_avatar)

    set @id_usuario = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    insert into Imagenes
    (id_usuario, Picture, Picture_name)
    values (@id_usuario, @Picture, @Picture_name)
```

Comment: I'll add that you can put all of this into a single sql statement string in your c# client code. You don't need to send separate commands for each step.